# Carrierwave Uploading XML file and ruby-nmap not finding it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nmap

I'm trying to use Carrierwave to upload files, and then after the upload is complete, use the ruby-nmap XML parser to populate some fields.

I set a sleep timer to 8 to just make sure the files are getting uploaded. I've set this as much as 20. I can see them getting uploaded and are in the correct directory. However, ruby-nmap says it cannot find the file as if it doesn't exist.

I generated a simple scaffold and I'm manipulating the "def create" portion.

controller code:

```
def create
@nmapfile = Nmapfile.new(nmapfile_params)
@nmapfile.nmapfilerecords = 0
@nmapfile.save
sleep 8
Nmap::XML.new(@nmapfile.nmapxml.to_s) do |xml|
    xml.each_host do |host|
      if "#{host.status}" == "down"            
      else
        @nmapfile.nmapfilerecords += 1
      end
    end
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @nmapfile.save
    format.html { redirect_to @nmapfile, notice: 'nmap file was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @nmapfile }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @nmapfile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:
Errno::ENOENT  in NmapfilesController#create  (No such file or directory - /uploads/nmapfile/nmapxml/21/scan.xml)

Yet, scan.xml DOES exist in that directory.

I ran this just as a simple ruby script at it works. The output shows 11 on the console screen. So there isn't an issue with the file. It's there.

```
require 'nmap/xml'
nmapfilerecords = 0
Nmap::XML.new('/Users/colemk1/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/JumpSquares/public/uploads/nmapfile/nmapxml/21/scan.xml') do |xml|
    xml.each_host do |host|
      if "#{host.status}" == "down"            
      else
        nmapfilerecords += 1
      end
    end
   puts nmapfilerecords
end
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

come to find out, the Nmap XML parser needs to have the FULL path.

setting the full path made it work correctly:

```
Nmap::XML.new('/Users/colemk1/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/JumpSquares/public/' + @nmapfile.nmapxml.to_s) do |xml|
```

or use the rails root path

```
Nmap::XML.new("#{Rails.root}/public/" + @nmapfile.nmapxml.to_s) do |xml|
```